# Footnote is creating a page break

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I'm using beamer and used footnote, however it would introduce a page break, note that change the size of my beamer didn't help.

```
 \documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=table]{beamer}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{Header}
\begin{itemize}
\item Solve $x^2y''-2xy'+2y=2x^3\textrm{e}^x$ 
\begin{itemize}
\item $y_1=x^2, y_2=x, r(x)=2x\textrm{e}^x$
\item W\footnote{ $y_p=-y_1\int \dfrac{y_2r(x)}{W}\, dx+ y_2 ont\dfrac{y_1r(x)}{W}$} 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: For the equation in the `footnote`, change `\dfrac` to `\frac`.

Comment: Off-topic: You should replace all instances of `\textrm{e}` with `\mathsf{e}`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What does "ont" denote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions/observations:

- Use inline-fraction notation in the footnote instead of `\dfrac` or `\frac`
- Use `\mathsf{e}` rather than `\mathrm{e}` to denote `\exp(1)`
- Write the material in the first level-2 item as three separate formulas

As a (welcome) side-effect of these changes, the spurious page break will disappear on its own.

[image]
...
[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Header}
\begin{itemize}
\item Solve $x^2y''-2xy'+2y=2x^3\mathsf{e}^x$ 
\begin{itemize}
\item $y_1=x^2$, $y_2=x$, $r(x)=2x\mathsf{e}^x$
\item W\footnote{$y_p=-y_1\int\! y_2r(x)/W\, dx+ y_2 ont\, y_1r(x)/W$} 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The size of the equation is too big, it flows out of the footnote area and causes a new page to be generated.

The easiest way to fix this is to use `\frac` instead of `\dfrac`

MWE:

```
 \documentclass[]{beamer}
 
 \begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Header}

\begin{itemize}
\item Solve $x^2y''-2xy'+2y=2x^3\textrm{e}^x$ 
\begin{itemize}
\item $y_1=x^2, y_2=x, r(x)=2x\textrm{e}^x$
\item W\footnote{$y_p=-y_1\int \frac{y_2r(x)}{W}\, dx+ y_2 ont\frac{y_1r(x)}{W}$} 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

 \end{document}
```